# Changing column name of part of DF, not working

Tags: python, dataframe, rename

Hi I would like to change the column names of a part of the columns in my dataframe.
When I print just the part I want to change it to: `palColAdj.iloc[:, 73:].columns.str[:-2]` I see the outcome I would like to see, but when I try to change it in my original dataframe I don't see the change.

So if I write either

```
palColAdj.iloc[:, 73:].columns=palColAdj.iloc[:, 73:].columns.str[:-2]
```

or

```
prodColAdj.iloc[:, 39:].columns=prodColAdj.iloc[:, 39:].columns.str[:-2].to_list()
```

and afterwards I print

```
prodColAdj.head()
```

I still see the original column names. How can this be?

Comment: Have you changed the column names inplace? Pandas generally has an `inplace=True` option if you made any changes which you would want to reflect in the original dataframe, though I cannot clearly understand the problem from the question.

Comment: I guess the problem is that the columns of  `df.iloc[:, 73:]` are not columns of `df`. Therefore, the changes you apply to `df.iloc[:, 73:].columns` doesn't affect `df.columns`. If you want to change `df.coumns`, you may do `df.columns = df.iloc[:, :a].columns.to_list() + df.iloc[:, a:].columns.str[1:].to_list()` or use `df.rename()` etc.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the explanation and answer. This worked:
`prodColAdj.columns = prodColAdj.iloc[:, :39].columns.to_list() + prodColAdj.iloc[:, 39:].columns.str[:-2].to_list()`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
                    columns=['aaaa', 'bbbb', 'ccccc']) 
#    aaaa  bbbb  ccccc
# 0     1     2      3
# 1     4     5      6
# 2     7     8      9

cols = df2.columns.values

dict = {}
for col in cols:
    dict[col] = col[:-2]

df.rename(dict, axis=1, inplace=True)
#      aa    bb    ccc
# 0     1     2      3
# 1     4     5      6
# 2     7     8      9
```

To pick specific cols, edit this:

```
cols = df2.columns.values[0:2]
# array(['aaaa', 'bbbb'], dtype=object)
```